# c# convert byte[] to byte but keep value the same

Tags: c#

So i have a program that communicates through tcp, the server was already done, but i don't understand how to convert the byte[] to byte but keeping the value the same.

```
public static List<byte[]> Separate(byte[] source, byte[] separator)
{
    List<byte[]> list = new List<byte[]>();
    int num = 0;
    byte[] array;
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Equals(source, separator, i))
        {
            array = new byte[i - num];
            Array.Copy(source, num, array, 0, array.Length);
            list.Add(array);
            num = i + separator.Length;
            i += separator.Length - 1;
        }
    }
    array = new byte[source.Length - num];
    Array.Copy(source, num, array, 0, array.Length);
    list.Add(array);
    return list;
}

private static bool Equals(byte[] source, byte[] separator, int index)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < separator.Length; i++)
    {
        if (index + i >= source.Length || source[index + i] != separator[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static byte[] delimiter = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<EOM>");
private static byte[] end = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<EOF>");

public static IServerPacket BuildPacket(byte[] _data)
{
    try
    {
        List<byte[]> list = new List<byte[]> { _data };
        byte b = list[0].ToList().GetRange(0, 1)[0];
        IServerPacket result = null;
        List<byte> list2 = list[0].ToList();
        list2.RemoveRange(0, 6);
        list[0] = list2.ToArray();
        list = Separate(Separate(list[0], end)[0], delimiter);
        //printing list[0][0] here gives me 50 instead of 2

    switch (b)
        {
            case 1:
                result = new Start(1, list[0][0]);
                break;
            case 2:
                result = new Stop();
                break;
            case 3:
                result = new MouseEvnt(list[0][0], list[1][0], list[2], list[3], list[4][0]);
                break;
            case 4:
                result = new KeyEvnt(list[0][0], list[1][0]);
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    return null;
}
```

what i'm sending with the server : `1<EOM>2<EOM>3<EOM>4<EOM>5<EOM>6<EOM>` , printing list[0][0] will give me `50` instead of `2`. tried everything but i just couldn't make it work..

Comment: **Bytes are not characters**. `50` is the decimal value for the ascii character `2`. If you want to see a `2`, cast the byte as a `char`

Comment: An array of bytes (`byte[]`) does not have the same value as a single byte (`byte`), so it's a bit unclear what your question is asking...

Comment: the client is not made by me, i'm simply trying to figure out how to make this work as it is (without converting it to char)

Comment: @Austin exactly, i need this to work without modifying it because then i'd have to change every single byte to char plus other changes, i only have the client, the server is supposed to send a different value to work along with the client

Comment: Yes, you may have to change every single `byte` to `char` to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be **MUCH** more aware of the types you already have and resulting types of each expression within a statement. So much of the original code in this method was simply not doing anything productive at all, just to get back to the original value you already had. There's no reason for any of that code in the question to ever convert those byte arrays to List.

```
public static IServerPacket BuildPacket(byte[] _data)
{
    byte b = _data[0];
    IServerPacket result = null;

    switch ((char)b)
    {
        case '1':
            result = new Start(1, b);
            break;
        case '2':
            result = new Stop();
            break;
        case '3':
            result = new MouseEvnt(b, _data[1], _data[2], _data[3], _data[4]);
            break;
        case '4':
            result = new KeyEvnt(b, _data[1]);
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Alternatively you can keep the ascii values, which might be more efficient:

```
public static IServerPacket BuildPacket(byte[] _data)
{
    byte b = _data[0];
    IServerPacket result = null;

    switch (b)
    {
        case 49:
            result = new Start(1, b);
            break;
        case 50:
            result = new Stop();
            break;
        case 51:
            result = new MouseEvnt(b, _data[1], _data[2], _data[3], _data[4]);
            break;
        case 52:
            result = new KeyEvnt(b, _data[1]);
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Not sure on the event objects, since I can't see how they work, but I suspect this is pretty close.

Comment: hey, the client is not made by me, but the thing is that i have to change a lot of stuff from byte to char to make it work, what i was trying to do is make it work "as it is". also the server is supposed to send some random numbers as well

Comment: i cannot use the first example because i have to change a lot of places to accept char instead of bytes, and i cannot use the second one because the server is supposed to send random mouse coordinates and that will mess it up

Comment: In both examples, `b` is a byte, not a char.